# Equivalent of aws.sqs.approximate_number_of_messages_visible in Kinesis

Tags: amazon-sqs, metrics, amazon-kinesis

I know that the aws.sqs.approximate_number_of_messages_visible is the 'The number of messages available for retrieval from the queue'. What would the equivalent be if I am to use Kinesis and wanting to retrieve similar types of metrics. I only managed to find aws.kinesis.IncomingRecords but am unsure if that is the equivalent

---